# PHPMailer Attachment error

Tags: php, pdf, smtp, attachment, phpmailer

I'm trying to send via PHPMailer - http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ emails with attachment.

`$ mail-> AddAttachment ($ file, basename ($ file), "base64", mime_content_type ($ file));`

Annex ever comes alright sometimes comes damaged (for example, from 300 kb size comes just 72 Kb). Specifically, I try to PDF files.

thank you

I use SMTP

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have directly provide path of pdf It is working fine for me.

```
 $mail->AddAttachment('PDF FILE PATH');
```

Please refer this link [Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/send-mail-using-phpmailer-en/