# How can I install mime_mail on my server?

Tags: php, email, mime, mime-mail

How can I install it, and use it to attach photos to emails I send from my server?

I get the photos from an android app.

I got that file, mime.php, and I have no Idea what I have to do with it.

Php code:

```
<?php 

$target = "upload/"; 
$name="id";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'].$name); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "yes";
} 
else {
echo "no";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u'd like to use phpmailer class [phpmailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

[Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)