# how to send an attachment to email from input tag

Tags: php, email, post

I want to send an attachment to email through html file input.
So far this is my code, i am able to send mail but not the ataachment

```
    <?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$services = $_POST['services'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$formcontent=" First Name: $fname \n Last Name: $lname \n Address: $address \n City:$city \n Postal Code:$zip \n Country: $country \n Position Applied for: $position \n email: $email  \n Services Required: $services \n  Resume: $filename";

$recipient = "rohit@gmail.com";
$subject = "Clinogent - Job Application";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
  <html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function load(){
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href="http://www.clinogent.com/currentopeningapply.html";
            },0);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="load();">
</body>
 </html>
```

How do i proceed further

Comment: What file are you working with? Are you generating the attachment?

Comment: no i am not generating any attachment, simple upload from desktop

Answer (score 0):

This is the great PHP Mailer class:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Already solved your Problem:

[Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)