# How to attach file to email from PC using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, file-upload, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have problem when I'm trying to send e-mail via form on my website with file attached.
I'm using PHPMailer, mail is always sent, but always without attached file.

I have no idea what should I fix or add to my code.

I've been looking on some tutorials, how to use PHPMailer and attach files.

Code is below:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="Name"><br />
<input type="text" name="email" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="Email"><br />
<input type="text" name="phone" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="Phone"><br />
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br />
<input type="submit" name="send" id="gobutton" value="Send">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
  <?
require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

if (isset($_POST['odeslat'])){
  $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-excel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-msexcel")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] ."')</script>";
    }
  else
    {
        $d='upload/';
        $de=$d . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $de);
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     //add only if the file is an upload
     }
  }
else
  {
  echo "<script>alert('Invalid file')</script>";
  }

$to = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();



$mail->From = "info@mywebsite.com";
$mail->FromName = "My website";



$mail->addAddress("mail@mail.com");
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);


$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
   header ("Location: /?e=1");
} 
else 
{
header ("Location: /?s=1");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to start by looking in the `$_FILES` superglobal. That's where you'll find data on the uploaded file. Check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Read the docs and the examples provided with PHPmailer. Advice you find elsewhere is likely to be wrong or outdated.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the need to keep the file on the system, you can directly send the file like this :

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']) &&
  $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

  //check MIME TYPE
  $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  if (false === $ext = array_search(
    $finfo->file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
    array(
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
        'gif' => 'image/gif',
    ),
    true
  )) {
      throw new RuntimeException('Invalid file format.');
  }
  $destination = sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s',
       sha1_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']),
       $ext
  );

  //move the file to a temp folder
  if (!move_uploaded_file(
    $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
    $destination
  )) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to move uploaded file.');
  }

  //Attach file
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],
                     basename($destination));
  //delete the file
  unlink($destination);
}
```

[This subject has already been treated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

Comment: I've edited my question with solution which worked for me

Comment: Don't do this, it's a security risk.

Comment: @Synchro, can you please develop ?

Comment: Read [the PHPDocs on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). It's quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

[Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

Basicly you need the tmp name that was uploaded to your server and the name of the file

```
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']
$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already found solution here, in another topic, it worked great for me too.

Comment: @HSturma : You have to Search for your requirements then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing, and what is suggested in other answers, is horribly wrong.

If you have no clue about things like this, perhaps you should try [reading the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) **first**?

Using `$_FILES` properties directly has security implications that are mitigated by using [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), which you are avoiding for no apparent reason.

There is [an example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) that does exactly what you ask, but without the security holes. To paraphrase the most important part:

```
if (array_key_exists('fileToUpload', $_FILES)) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
    }
}
```

For a more thorough implementation of validating uploads before using them, see [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004) in the PHP docs.