# File attachment with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an HTML form with the option to upload a file.
I would like then to send that file as an attachment to the email address along with the rest of the form data.
I'm using PHP Mailer and I get the form data to send: such as name, telephone number, etc.

I can't get the image to send along with it. I've provided the code I have so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id='contactus' action='contact.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>

<fieldset >
<legend>Contact us</legend>


<div class='container'>
  
    <label for='email' >Name*:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required /><br>
    <label for='email' >Phone*:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required /><br>
    <label for='email' >Email*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' required/><br/>
 
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'></textarea>
    <br>
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input id="file" name="image" type="file" />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
      
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");
      
      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a PDF, JPEG or PNG file.";
      }
      
      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }
      
      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name); //The folder where you would like your file to be saved
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }

// PHPMailer script below

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
require("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

$mail->Username = "yoursmtp@username.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "hidden"; // SMTP password
$mail->addAttachment("uploads/".$file_name);
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587; //SMTP port
$mail->addAddress("your@email.com", "your name");
$mail->Subject = "You have an email from a website visitor!";
$mail->Body ="
Name: $name<br>
Email: $email<br>
Telephone: $phone<br><br><br>
Comments: $message";
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "<script>alert('Message has been sent')</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you call

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
```

This creates a file in the `uploads/` directory with the name of the file as it was named on the uploader's computer.

Then you used sample code to add the attachment to phpMailer so you're basically attempting to attach non-existent files.

These two lines:

```
$mail->addAttachment('uploads/file.tar.gz');   // I took this from the phpmailer example on github but I'm not sure if I have it right.      
$mail->addAttachment('uploads/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');
```

should be changed to:

```
$mail->addAttachment("uploads/".$file_name);
```

Also note, it isn't necessary to call `move_uploaded_file` if you don't want to save the attachment after its uploaded and emailed.  If that's the case just call `AddAttachment` with `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` as the file argument.

Also, in your HTML form, you have

```
<input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
```

but refer to the input as `image` in the code.  You should change the name of that input from `file` to `image`.

To only attach the image and not save it take out the `move_uploaded_file` code and add:

```
$file_tmp  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
//...
$mail->AddAttachment($file_tmp, $file_name);
```

Comment: Still no dice! I really appreciate the help btw
I'm thinking maybe the problem is lying with the file not actually uploading to anywhere temporarily. When I upload a file, Chrome shows me a progress report at the bottom of the screen e.g 50% > 90%, so I know the browser is in fact registering that the file is being uploaded
But when it tries to grab the file and attach it, nothing happens
Here is the link incase you can see anything useful
www.elisweb.co.uk/form

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php/11764230#11764230).  It's pretty much exactly what you're trying to do.  Also you can check `$_FILES['image']['error']` to make sure there are no PHP errors with the file upload.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that one, I'll go back and try again though! I'd upvote your answer for all the help you've given me but my rep isn't high enough yet
I'm quite new to stack-overflow so I'm not sure what to do about marking the answer as correct. Since you corrected my code, I would mark your answer as correct, or would that be misleading since I'm still having problems??

Comment: Do you want to edit your original post with the code you have currently and I can spot if anything is wrong with it that might be causing the upload not to work?

Comment: I finally managed! Thanks Drew! I had the code wrong for uploading the file to the server. I used this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm)
 to help me with that and your answer to fix the code in my HTML and PHPMailer script

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->addAttachment("uploads/".$file_name);
```

Just use above code before php mailer send function