# send files with phpmailer from a location on my server

Tags: phpmailer

This may be answered already, but I can't figure out how to word my search.

I am using phpmailer to send some pictures , but i want to send pictures that have been uploaded to my server. By another script. So, how do I attach multiple files that are on my server?

I guess Im asking how to I add a path to the files instead of uploading it at the time I am sending it?

Comment: Once you have uploaded the images to your server, get the path to them and attach them to PHPMailer messages using `addAttachment`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File attachment with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997961/file-attachment-with-phpmailer)

Comment: This is what I needed $mail->addAttachment("uploads/".$file_name);  Thank you