# How to send a file using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I just went through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12302354/4381665), as how to send a file in PHP using PHPMailer. I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action="./php/send-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="file" name="files" id="filer_input" multiple="multiple">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code as below:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'gautam@webmunky.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->AddAddress( 'gautam@webmunky.com' );

<!-- $file_to_attach = $_FILES['files']; -->
$email->AddAttachment( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['files']['name'] );
return $email->Send();
```

I believe I am making a mistake in the below two lines of code:

```
<!-- $file_to_attach = $_FILES['files']; -->
$email->AddAttachment( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['files']['name'] );
```

but I am not sure. How can I send my file using the above PHP code?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What is this `<!-- $file_to_attach = $_FILES['files']; -->` that's not how we comment code in php blocks, just saying.  Pretty sure that is a syntax error, change it to `//$file_to_attach = $_FILES['files'];`

Comment: Store your image file from temp to your project root directory and then give path to attachment.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11764230/5830872

Comment: How about looking at [the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/) that do exactly what you ask, without the security holes?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is a syntax error

```
<?php
      <!-- $file_to_attach = $_FILES['files']; -->
```

This is an HTML comment, when you want a PHP comment.

```
<?php
  //$file_to_attach = $_FILES['files'];
```

Or even

```
<?php
  #$file_to_attach = $_FILES['files'];
```