# How to add attachment to PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Users can add an attachment to the contact on my website but i do not now how to include the attachment in the PHPMailer script, anybody has an idea?

**PHPMailer:** http://pastebin.com/B2Wj9nur
**HTML:** http://pastebin.com/qwNsxD4r

Comment: There's a couple of explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a look, not tested.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
    $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
}


$mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe'); 
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last'); 
//....
//other email code
$mail->Send();
```