# PHPMailer form not sending attachments

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, attachment

I'm trying to implement a contact form using PHPMailer but I can't make the attachment from the upload field to be sent. The contact form do work and all the other fields are sent.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial) with no luck.

Also tried numerous different PHP scripts such as [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/phpmailer-contact-form-adding-attachments-doesnt-work), [this](http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/attach-a-file-to-an-email-in-php-using-phpmailer) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php) one, among others.

The current code I have that seems to be the most successfully used is this one:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 // Attack #1 preventor - Spam Honeypot

    if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
        echo "SPAM HONEYPOT";
        exit;
    }

    // Attack #2 preventor - Email header injection hack preventor 

    foreach($_POST as $value) {
        if(stripos($value, 'Content-Type:') !== FALSE) {
            echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";
            exit;
        }
    }

if (isset($_POST['inputNome']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputMensagem'])) {

    //check if any of the inputs are empty
   if (empty($_POST['inputNome']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputMensagem'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Preencha todos os campos requeridos.');
        echo ($data);
        exit;

    }

    //create an instance of PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
      // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "************";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "*************"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "*********"; // Your Gmail password

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

     // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['inputEmail'], $_POST['inputNome']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['inputEmail'], $_POST['inputNome']);
    $mail->Subject = "My Company - " . $_POST['inputAssunto'];      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->AddAddress('name@myemail.com'); //recipient  

     //Add attachment
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['inputBriefing']);
       if (isset($_FILES['inputBriefing']) &&
           $_FILES['inputBriefing']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
           $mail->addAddress($_FILES['inputBriefing']['tmp_name'],
                               $_FILES['inputBriefing']['name']);
     }
    $mail->Body = "Nome: " . $_POST['inputNome'] . "\r\nEmail: " . $_POST['inputEmail'] . "\r\nTelefone: " .$_POST['inputTelefone'] . "\r\nAssunto: " . $_POST['inputAssunto'] . "\r\nMensagem: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMensagem']);


  if(!$mail->send())
{
   echo 'An error has occurred.';
   exit;
}

echo 'Message successfully sent';
}

?>
```

And the form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/form-contact.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputNome">Nome Completo *</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputNome" name="inputNome" required class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail">E-mail *</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" required class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputTelefone">Telefone</label>
        <input type="tel" id="inputTelefone" name="inputTelefone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAssunto">Assunto</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="inputAssunto" name="inputAssunto" >
            <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione -- </option>
            <option value="Orçamento">Orçamento</option>
            <option value="Hospedagem">Hospedagem</option>
            <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
            <option value="Informações">Informações</option>
            <option value="Outro">Outro</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBriefing">Briefing</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
        <input type="file" id="inputBriefing" name="inputBriefing">
        <p class="help-block">Se preferir adicione seus arquivos (.pdf, .docx ou .zip)</p>
    </div>
    <!--Hpam Sponypot -->
    <div class="form-group" style="visibility: hidden">     
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id ="address">  
        <p> Humans, do not fill out this form! </p>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputMensagem">Mensagem *</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="inputMensagem" name="inputMensagem" required placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"></textarea>
    </div>
    <p><small>* Campos obrigatórios.</small></p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

I'm using a shared host on Hostgator.

Comment: Please [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) You are not referencing the file in your attempt to add an attachment

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you I updated my code above but I still don't get the attachment. Instead the form returns the following error: "Notice: Undefined index: inputBriefing in /home/user/public_html/...l/form-contact.php on line 55"

Comment: @RiggsFolly As I said on the question I was following this tutorial and that's what I think this is doing: http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/attach-a-file-to-an-email-in-php-using-phpmailer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly And again thank you for marking me down without checking my sources and mocking me instead of providing any valid help.

Comment: I did check your source

Answer (score 0):

You were attempting to add the file as a new destination address and not an attachment.

See below for suggested amendment.

```
//Add attachment
// $_FILES['inputBriefing'] is an array not the file
// adding the file as an attachment before checking for errors is a bad idea also
//$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['inputBriefing']);
if (isset($_FILES['inputBriefing']) && $_FILES['inputBriefing']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    // this is attempting to add an address to send the email to
    //$mail->addAddress($_FILES['inputBriefing']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['inputBriefing']['name']);
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['inputBriefing']['tmp_name'],
                           $_FILES['inputBriefing']['name']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add enctype in you form tag like this.

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/form-contact.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Try this form tag