# php mail attachment not working my code

Tags: php, html

I have not working this code.i want to send mail to the email id but it woudnt happened,  I have not working this code.i want to send mail to the email id but it woudnt happened ,  I have not working this code.i want to send mail to the email id but it woudnt happened ,code as below:-

```
         <h2>Your Contact Info</h2>
          <p>Your First Name* <br />
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required />
          </p>
          <p>Your Last Name* <br />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required />
          </p>
          <p>Your Email* <br />
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
          </p>
          <p>Upload Your logo<br />
            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file"> 
          </p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" />
         </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $emailAddress = 'xyz@gmail.com';
     $mail=$_POST['email'];
     require_once('php/_lib/class.phpmailer.php');
    $msg = 'First Name:'.$_POST['firstName'].'<br /> Last name:'.$_POST['lastName'].'<br /> Email:'.$_POST['email'].'<br />';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->IsMail();
      $mail->AddReplyTo($mail);
      $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
      $mail->From($mail);
      $mail->Subject = "Subject";
      $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
      $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
      $mail->Send();

        enter code here

      echo'<script> window.location="../index.html"; </script> ';
    }
      ?>
```

Comment: check the php mailer docs for the correct usage of `AddAttachment()` because i am pretty sure you did not use it right

Comment: Please refer the below thread of Stackoverflow for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail

Comment: you really need to improve on how you explain your problems though. The message body of your question makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Initially $mail is an email address then it becomes a PHPMailer object then the AddReplyTo is set to be PHPMailer Object ( That's not very strange!!! ).

So for starters change

```
$mail=$_POST['email'];
```

To

```
$reply_to_email=$_POST['email'];
```

And then change...

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($mail);
```

To

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($reply_to_email);
```

And you need to validate that $_POST['email'] is an email address and not someones shopping list etc... You are open to attack with that form.

**Whoops I missed more misuse of $mail...**

```
$mail->From($mail);
```

Should be, or rather, not be the above...

```
$mail->From($respond_to_email);
```

Change the names to suit, but do not call them $mail!

**UPDATE:**
In Addressing your "stated issue" and without regurgitating the answer here, go and read up on how to use [$mail->AddAttachment Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

Comment: just curious but was this `$mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);` used right?

Comment: @Akintunde Yep, but I wasn't addressing that... just this glaring foobar. You are correct in the OP requiring to read up on how to use $mail->AddAttachment().

Comment: Where does it end!