# Phpmailer sends mail without physical file

Tags: php, phpmailer, attachment

I use Phpmailer to send emails, but have a problem with sending an attachment. I tried this:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/test.pdf','doklad.pdf');
```

and this:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/test.pdf','doklad.pdf','base64','application/pdf');
```

and this:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment(file_get_contents($_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/test.pdf'),'doklad.pdf','base64','application/pdf');
```

Phpmailer always sends an attachment but no physical file.

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

Comment: Additionally please check with `file_exists` if `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/test.pdf'` exists and has correct path.

Comment: What do you mean by "Phpmailer always sends an attachment but no physical file."? That makes no sense! Also, check the return value of all of these.

Comment: File exists, its content is sent in source, email has 1.2 MB, but no physical attachment.

Comment: Problem is that I use also AddEmbeddedImage. If image is not embeded, attachment is sent as physical file. So...? :-O

Comment: SOLVED: New version of Phpmailer (6.0.5) solved it.